# How do I update a nested record in BigQuery using DML syntax?

Tags: google-bigquery

I've got the following BigQuery schema, and I'm trying to update the `event_dim.date` field:

[image]

I tried the following query using standard SQL and the new BigQuery DML:

```
UPDATE `sara-bigquery.examples.app_events_20170113`
SET event_dim.date = '20170113'
WHERE true
```

But got this error:

```
Error: Cannot access field date on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<name STRING, params ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING, 
value STRUCT<string_value STRING, int_value INT64, float_value FLOAT64, ...>>>, timestamp_micros INT64, ...>> at [2:15]
```

I'm able to select the nested field with this query:

```
 SELECT x.date FROM `sara-bigquery.examples.app_events_20170113`,
 UNNEST(event_dim) x
```

But can't figure out the correct `UPDATE` syntax.

Answer (score 9):

That query failed because `event_dim` is an array of structs. This should do the trick:

```
UPDATE `sara-bigquery.examples.app_events_20170113`
SET event_dim = ARRAY(
  SELECT AS STRUCT * REPLACE('20170113' AS date) FROM UNNEST(event_dim)
)
WHERE true
```

Check out the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays) on how arrays are handled in Standard SQL for more details.

Comment: Note that you would need to escape the table name with backticks since it contains a `-`.

Comment: Thanks for catching that @ElliottBrossard, fixed.